# Jquery show () does not work after closing panel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this routine in a plugin that I'm building for wordpress. The problem is that the button to show and hide the form does not work right. It only works when I close the panel, when I try to click again to open it, nothing happens and I do not see any errors in my console.

```
EsconderPainelImportacao = function(){
    $('div#panel_mega_importer').hide();
    $('#link_btn_panel').html("<a href='javascript:void(0);' style='text- 
    decoration:none;' id='link_btn_panel' 
    onClick='MostarPainelImportacao();' title='Mostrar Painel'><i 
    id='hide_form_mega_importer' class='fas fa-eye'></i></a> Visualizar 
    FormulÃ¡rio ImportaÃ§Ã£o");
}

MostarPainelImportacao = function(){
    console.log($('div#panel_mega_importer').length);
    $('div#panel_mega_importer').show();
    $('#link_btn_panel').html("<a href='javascript:void(0);' style='text- 
    decoration:none;' id='link_btn_panel' 
    onClick='EsconderPainelImportacao();' title='Esconder Painel'><i 
    id='hide_form_mega_importer' class='fas fa-eye'></i></a>");
}
```

[My Full code](https://jsfiddle.net/RaizenDevil/v7w2s0zg/10/)

Comment: you have an option to use .toggle() like in `MostarPainelImportacao ` use `$('div#panel_mega_importer').toggle();` but for this you will have to click the text, but you can apply this on which ever html tag you like possibly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your full code, i can see you are changing the HTML of the button itself, you need to change the html of his parent who is a **div** with class **col-md-12**. So, try next modifications:

```
EsconderPainelImportacao = function(){
    $('div#panel_mega_importer').hide();
    $('#link_btn_panel').parent().html("<a href='javascript:void(0);' style='text- 
    decoration:none;' id='link_btn_panel' 
    onClick='MostarPainelImportacao();' title='Mostrar Painel'><i 
    id='hide_form_mega_importer' class='fas fa-eye'></i></a> Visualizar 
    FormulÃ¡rio ImportaÃ§Ã£o");
}

MostarPainelImportacao = function(){
    console.log($('div#panel_mega_importer').length);
    $('div#panel_mega_importer').show();
    $('#link_btn_panel').parent().html("<a href='javascript:void(0);' style='text- 
    decoration:none;' id='link_btn_panel' 
    onClick='EsconderPainelImportacao();' title='Esconder Painel'><i 
    id='hide_form_mega_importer' class='fas fa-eye'></i></a>");
}
```